# why does the variable inside the loop count from 012 but the variable outside of the loop count from 0123?

Tags: javascript

this is the code in question, I'd like to know why the inside loop variable counts from 0,1,2 and the outside variable counts from 0,1,2,3

```js
let i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  console.log(i);
}

console.log(i);
```

Comment: it doesn't count again from 01,2,3 but only 3 which is the last value of `i`

Comment: Basic logic: i is zero, do stuff.... next iteration, i is one, do stuff, next iteration i is two, do stuff, next iteration, i is three, we are done..... outside loop, i is three.... SOunds like a good time to do some tutorials on for and while loops.

Answer (score 0):

`i++` is incrementing `i` each time until `i == 3`, then it breaks out of the `for` loop. So your `console.log(i)` inside the loop runs until it hits 3 then the `console.log(i)` outside the loop gets run once - after `i` is already equal to `3`

Answer (score 0):

`let i = 0;` at this level, your variable `i` is worth `0`

The variable i is incremented from 0 to 2. so at the end of the loop the variable `i = 2` `console.log(i)` will print `2`

```js
let i = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
   console.log(i) // this will print 0, 1, 2
}

console.log(i) // this will print 2
```